# Twig variable error

Tags: twig

I have array in PHP:

```
    array(
        'name1' => 'one',
        'name2' => 'two',
        'name3' => 'three'
    )
```

but in twig:

```
    {% for i in range(1, 3) %}
        {{'name' ~ i}}
    {% endfor %}
```

give me:

```
    1
    2
    3
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
  {% for i in range(1, 3) %}
        {{ attribute(_context, 'name' ~ i) }}
  {% endfor %}
```

To have:

```
one
two
three
```